# javascript replace &reg; and html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to remove as many common cases as possible of ® and uniform it across the site.

I want all of them to look like:

Dashing Company<sup>®</sup>

Here is what I'm working with thus far:

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <p>Dashing Company&reg;</p>
    <p>Dashing Company<sub>&reg;</sub></p>
    <p>Dashing Company<span>&reg;</span></p>
    <p>Dashing Company<sup>&reg;</sup></p>
</body>
```

**Javascript / jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").html(
        $("body").html()
            .replace("<sub>&reg;</sub>", "&reg;")
            .replace('<div>&reg;</div>', "&reg;")
            .replace('<span>&reg;</span>', "&reg;")
            .replace('<sup>&reg;</sup>', "&reg;")
            .replace("®", "&reg;")
            .replace(/&reg;/g, '&reg;')
            .replace(/®/g, '&reg;')
            .replace("\u00AE" , '&reg;')
            .replace('&reg;', '<sup>&reg;</sup>')
    ); 
});
```

Fiddle time (updated): http://fiddle.jshell.net/w94z8vf1/8/

How do I make all of the `<p>`'s contain `<sup>&reg;</sup>` alone (next to the company name)?

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: What's you want in this code ?

Comment: `<p>Dashing Company<div>&reg;</div></p>` is invalid html

Comment: [Your jsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/w94z8vf1/1/) would work better if you included the jQuery library.

Comment: I believe [this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/w94z8vf1/7/) does what you want. If you make your question clearer I can post it as an answer. Although, it may fail the case of the `<p>Dashing Company<div>&reg;</div></p>` because it is indeed invalid HTML and cannot be parsed correctly in the DOM.

Comment: Ok, removing `div` as case. Thanks Dave!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `contents().unwrap()` function to remove the `<sub>`, `<span>`, `<div>` etc..

```
$('sup').contents().unwrap();
```

Comment: How do you know what the OP is asking?

Comment: @Sparky, I dont, but the code about him replacing every element seems very obsolete. So here is a better example for more people who want to know how to replace tags but keep the content.

Comment: However, unless he fixes his question and gets it reopened, nobody else is going to see this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").html(
    $("body").html().replace("<sub>&reg;</sub>", "&reg;")
        .replace('<div>&reg;</div>', "&reg;")
        .replace('<span>&reg;</span>', "&reg;")
        .replace('<sup>&reg;</sup>', "&reg;")
        .replace('<sub>®</sub>', "&reg;")
        .replace('<sup>®</sup>', "&reg;")
        .replace('<div>®</div>', "&reg;")
   );
```

});

Notice: You can't have block elements inside of a paragraph, that's why the `<div>&reg;</div>` is outside of your paragraph tag.

Comment: How do you know what the OP is asking?

Comment: I saw his fiddle and just guessed, to be honest... EDIT: And he said "I want all of them to look like: [...]"

Comment: BTW, his jsFiddle doesn't do anything because he doesn't have any jQuery library selected.

Comment: Yeah, forgot to mention that. Thanks.